Request for page 247 of the book Theory of Martingales by Liptser, Shiryaev
I am looking for page 247 of the book Theory of Martingales by Liptser and Shiryaev. All the (legal) online versions I have found come from the same source, which is missing page 247 and incorrectly has page 259 in its place. If anyone has a hard copy of the book, I would greatly appreciate it if you could post a picture of that page.
P.S. I understand that this may be an unconventional request to post here, but I’m in a bit of a bind, so I’m taking the chance.

I don't see how there can be legal online versions of a book that is currently in copyright, in print and on sale. Can you not borrow a copy from a library? Making your own copy of a page for private use would then be legal.

@Rob Arthan I downloaded the PDF directly from the Springer website; when I click on the link I posted above, it allows me to download the PDF for free. Unfortunately, I don’t currently have access to a local library that holds this book.

I see. You must have been allowed to download it from Springer via your institution's subscription with them. I think you should raise the issue with Springer (or maybe get your institutions librarian to do that), but leave your question up here as someone may be able to provide you the missing page more quickly than waiting for Springer to respond.

I have access to the book at my uni, but are you sure you just need page 247?Pdf file seems missing 2,3 pages in a row to me.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1U2vj1r_VE2etU8aQtGdVOPai0nZItFZN/view?usp=drivesdk Here you go. Let me know if it is not the right page

@Tri, Perfect, that's exactly what I need. Thank you!

Glad your original problem has been solved: but don't forget to complain to Springer - they shouldn't be charging your institution for defective products.
